# use internal clock (ROSC) to set system clock (clk_sys) to run at 32 MHz in RP2040

Tags: c, pi-pico, system-clock

I am trying to set the system clock of my RP2040 to 32MHz using the internal clock(rosc) as source clock. When the pico board is powered on, the ROSC's frequency is around 5 MHz which lies in the range of possible frequencies the ROSC can be depending upon the V,P,T values(as per the data sheet). The API which needs to be used here is

```
clock_configure()
```

The parameters which needs to be passed are:
`clk_index` The clock to configure
`src` The main clock source, can be 0.
`auxsrc` The auxiliary clock source, which depends on which clock is being set. Can be 0
`src_freq` Frequency of the input clock source
`freq` Requested frequency

The values which I need be passed are: 1. clk_sys, 2. ROSC, 3. IDK what auxiliary clock is(even after reading the data sheet many times), 4. 5 MHz, 5. 32 MHz.

From the table given on [raspberrypi.github.io/pico-sdk-doxygen/group__hardware__clocks.html](https://raspberrypi.github.io/pico-sdk-doxygen/group__hardware__clocks.html) , I tried various combination of parameters, but nothing seemed to work. I do not understand the role of auxiliary clocks here and also I must be missing something in terms of logic to set the frequency using ROSC.
If someone has used internal clock to set the clk_sys to their desired value, then can you please highlight which details I am missing? And which other things (concepts) I need to understand well in order to achieve this task?

Thank You.